# lambda equivalent to sql update with joins

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I have 2 sets of data.

What would be the lambda syntax equivalent to this sql update statement ?

```
UPDATE Customers1
SET Customers1.Email = Customers2.Email
JOIN Customers2 ON Customers1.ID = Customers2.ID
```

Comment: You have to refine what are asking. As it stands, the question does not makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DanielHilgarth said just to use lambda or even LINQ is not enough here.

I assume you'd need something like:

```
foreach(var customer1 in customers1) {
    var customer2 = customers2.FirstOrDefault(c2 => customer1.ID.Equals(c2.ID));
    if (customer2 != null) customer1.Email = customers2.Email;
}
```

So, lambda is a chunk of the whole implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are just a way of writing anonymous methods: `x => { body }`. I assume you actually mean LINQ.

There is no equivalent, because the `Q` in LINQ stands for *query*. LINQ queries data, it doesn't change it.